# page-break-before style on element does not work

Tags: html, css

When a multipage form is printed, I want to force a page break before printing certail elements.  From what I have read here and elsewhere, the way to do this is to wrap the element in a block element which has the style "page-break-before: always."  I have tried to implement this, but printing still does not break where I want it to.  Here is my html:

```
<div class="page-break">
    <p style="text-align:center">Foo</p>
</div>
```

Here is the class definition in the css:

```
@media print {
    .page-break {
        display: block;
        page-break-before: always;
    }
```

Can anyone tell me why this would not work?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "break-before"?
[mozilla developer docs for "break-before"](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/break-before)

Comment: break-before appears to work in IE 10, but not in Chrome, where I had been doing my testing.

Comment: You test it by exporting a PDF in the print dialogue?

Comment: Break occurs at the desired place in IE 10 when output to printer or pdf. In Chrome, printing continues to page overflow on printer or pdf.